# Schedule power off with systemd

Tags: power, pi-4, systemd

I've enabled the following systemd unit file in order to properly shutdown my Raspberry Pi before a real timer in between cuts the power off. but it does a reboot, not the actual shutdown that I want.
Any idea?

systemd-poweroff.timer

```
[Unit]
Description=Poweroff every work day
# Call necessary service
Unit=systemd-poweroff.service

[Timer]
OnCalendar=Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri *-*-* 00:00:00
Persistent=false

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

Distributor ID: Raspbian

Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 9.11 (stretch)

Release:        9.11/
Codename:       stretch
Linux raspberrypi 4.19.66-v7+ #1253 SMP Thu Aug 15 11:49:46 BST 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux

Comment: Perhaps you should just try to halt rather than "poweroff" which the pi cannot do as such. Try a timer for `systemd-halt.service`.

Comment: There is a note here https://www.linux.org/docs/man8/systemd-shutdown.html that says never use that service but to use `systemctl halt` I ended up having a python program responding to mqtt and the scheduled task pushing the mqtt command!

Answer (score 5):

First of all: you are running **Raspbian Stretch** but tagged the question with `pi-4`. This is not possible. A Raspberry Pi 4B can only run **Raspbian Buster**.

Your timer Unit looks good and should do. But you define some default settings that are not necessary. This normally should not do any harm, but having problems it's always a good idea to configure with defaults. I have tested it with **Raspbian Buster Light**.

A systemd timer Unit calls by default a service of the same name, so a timer Unit named `systemd-poweroff.timer` will call a service of `systemd-poweroff.service` if not specified otherwise. So first check if this service is working as expected:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl start systemd-poweroff.service
```

Then the last messages on my screen are:

```
--- snip ---
[  OK  ] Reached target Shutdown.
[  OK  ] Reached target Final Step.
[  OK  ] Started Power-Off.
[399078.812158] reboot: Power down
```

I have to powercycle to restart the RasPi.

Then I created the timer with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl --force --full edit systemd-poweroff.timer
```

In the empty editor I inserted these statements, saved them and quit the editor:

```
[Unit]
Description=Poweroff every work day

[Timer]
#OnCalendar=Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri *-*-* 00:00:00
OnBootSec=180

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

For testing I used `OnBootSec=180`, which will poweroff the RasPi 3 minutes after bootup. Enable it now will poweroff the RasPi immediately because 3 minutes are already gone since last bootup.

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl enable --now systemd-poweroff.timer
```

This works as expected. I have to powercycle to restart the RasPi.

Check and stop the poweroff timer. You have 3 minutes to do it ;-)

```
rpi ~$ systemctl list-timers systemd-poweroff.timer
NEXT                         LEFT         LAST PASSED UNIT                   ACTIVATES
Tue 2020-05-26 12:40:28 BST  1min 5s left n/a  n/a    systemd-poweroff.timer systemd-poweroff.service

1 timers listed.

rpi ~$ sudo systemctl disable --now systemd-poweroff.timer
```